# More heap allocations (as opposed to doing nothing) make C++ code run faster

Tags: c++, optimization, heap-memory

I noticed a strange behavior in my C++ code. I have compared the performance of two different cases.

Case A) While parsing a file, I allocate many times an object (basically, one per file line, to simplify), and I put its pointer into a container (queue). I do not use this object anywhere else in the program, I just fill the container and never access the container anywhere else. Well, the code runs much faster with respect to the case B) below.

Case B) I comment out the part where I push the pointer into the dummy container, and as a result the program runs 10 times slower.

Thus it takes ten times for executing less code!

Let me copy the code snippet where I am playing with commenting things out:

In the case A) I have:

```
if (iKey.getBaseDepartureDate() <= iLastDepartureDateToLoad.get())
{
  BomHistoricalAvailabilityShr apBomHistoricalAvl = BomHistoricalAvailability::create();
  apBomHistoricalAvl->setAvailabilitySerializedKey(iKey);
  std::vector<char> aBlob(iBlob.begin(), iBlob.end());
  apBomHistoricalAvl->setAvailabilityData(aBlob);
  getLoaderQueue().pushBack(apBomHistoricalAvl);
  incrementNbOfKeysToLoadInDB();
}
else
{
  BomHistoricalAvailabilityShr apBomHistoricalAvl = BomHistoricalAvailability::create();
  apBomHistoricalAvl->setAvailabilitySerializedKey(iKey);
  std::vector<char> aBlob(iBlob.begin(), iBlob.end());
  apBomHistoricalAvl->setAvailabilityData(aBlob);
  _dummyQueue.push(apBomHistoricalAvl);
  incrementNbOfKeysToLoadInDB();
}
```

where the `_dummyQueue` is a member variable of type `std::queue<BomHistoricalAvailabilityShr>`, `BomHistoricalAvailabilityShr` is a typedef for a shared pointer.

In the case B) I have:

```
if (iKey.getBaseDepartureDate() <= iLastDepartureDateToLoad.get())
{
  BomHistoricalAvailabilityShr apBomHistoricalAvl = BomHistoricalAvailability::create();
  apBomHistoricalAvl->setAvailabilitySerializedKey(iKey);
  std::vector<char> aBlob(iBlob.begin(), iBlob.end());
  apBomHistoricalAvl->setAvailabilityData(aBlob);
  getLoaderQueue().pushBack(apBomHistoricalAvl);
  incrementNbOfKeysToLoadInDB();
}
```

namely I have just eliminated the `else` part. Sorry but I cannot copy the full code. If needed I can add more details. The `_dummyQueue` is never used anywhere else in the program. I just use this queue as a garbage in order to speed performance. Notice also that the problem is NOT related to smart pointers, I have tried with normal pointers, and it is just the same. I have also tried allocating integers or strings, and nothing changes.

How to solve this paradox? What could it be? How can optimize my program?

Comment: I don't suppose you could come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this?

Comment: With so little information, I'll bet on Debug vs Release mode (or GCC's `-O` level). Don't attempt to get meaningful benchmarks in Debug mode.

Comment: In fact, it's quite a big program, I'm just modifying a part of it. The point is that the container is never accessed later, and the pointers are never used later. I hope that someone could give me a hint. If nobody has a hint, I could copy-paste some parts of the code, but let me first see if there is a hint already (could be some heap fragmentation problem? or the compiler just generating crazy different instructions depending on one line of code being commented or not?).

Comment: OK, that is officially weird...

Comment: You need to show the function where you comment that line out. Is the pointer you put into the container a naked pointer or smart pointer? If a smart pointer, then it's obvious: you're paying the cost of deletion of the object, which is otherwise retained if the pointer goes into the container.

Comment: Here is the g++ compilation options I am using: `g++ -c -g -Wno-deprecated -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -fexceptions -Wall -Wmissing-field-initializers -fPIC`

Comment: `-O3` or `-O2` before you even think about performance making any sense.

Comment: @Kuba Ober. Actually I have tried commenting out the declaration of the pointer as well. So no pointer, no heap allocation, no push into containter, and the code is still slower...

Comment: I have tried also in "release" mode using these options: `g++ -c -Wno-deprecated -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -fexceptions -O2 -fno-tree-sra -Wall -Wmissing-field-initializers -fPIC` and apart from an overall performance improvement the result is just the same

Comment: I have re-edited my question including a part of the code. I know that strictly it is  not a SSCCE but I could not reproduce the problem in a simple way so far, so I have not come with a good SSCCE. Nevertheless I would like you to give me some hint for further investigations. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: You're doing much more than allocating an object in that code chunk.  Reduce that chunk of code until you find the exact line responsible.  Is it the allocation?  Is it some other function you're calling that has global side-effects?

Comment: @Peter. Thanks Peter, I did identify the line responsible for the speedup. It's the `create` line where I perform the heap allocation. More precisely, considering the code in case A), I have commented all the lines inside the `else` but the first one (the one with the call to `create`), run the program and the performance is very good. Then I have commented also the the first line so that I am left with an empty else block, and in this case the performance is very very bad. So any hint ? I'm desperate ... :-( I have tried with plain pointers as well, same results.

Comment: SSCCE is the only way to go.  The process of producing this will probably solve your problem.  For example, does a very simple processing stage show the same slowdown as your actual code?  If so, the issue is in your processing code.  Does the same thing happen if you replace your object class with something really simple?

Comment: @Peter. The same happens if in the else block I heap-allocate integers, strings or whatever (instead of complicated BomHistoricalAvailability objects). How can I profile this? I have tried Callgrind and it seems that under Callgrind there is no difference between the two scenarios, but maybe there is some correlation between Valgrind and the way the program executes. Or the bottleneck could be in the I/O part. But how can an allocation never used in the code speedup the I/O or the code in general ?

Comment: OK, now start reducing/switching out the processing portion of the code that times differently.  Also try allocating differently: does it work if you allocate the entire dummyQueue before the real input loop?  After?  Does it only work if interleaved?

Comment: @Peter. It works only if interleaved.